# Is it mandatory to have auto increment property for table in mysql even if we set autoincrement in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am getting the error like **id does not have default value**.In hibernate I used as follows

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Setter
@Getter
@Column(name="id")
private Long id;
```

But I didn't set auto increment for id in database side.Is it mandatory to set db side also.As per my knowledge hibernate can generate and set the value.

What might be the reason?Thanks in advance...

Comment: The way hibernate does that varies by sql dialect, and the way to do that with mysql is with an autoincremented column.

Comment: I set the dialect property also

Comment: @ElliottFrisch so you mean it is mandatory .Am I right ?

Comment: Unless you create your own *dialect*.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I mentioned mysqlDialect in applicationcontext.xml

Comment: And that is implemented the way I described. You **can** *create* your own (but it isn't trivial).

Comment: ok k I got it now.Thanks you

Answer (score 2):

if you create your schema manually you'll have to set the auto increment property to the ID column. if you let Hibernate generate your schema it will generate set it by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to Hibernate 5,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "post")
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    public Post() {}

    public Post(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

But for Hibernate 5,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "post")
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
        strategy= GenerationType.AUTO, 
        generator="native"
    )
    @GenericGenerator(
        name = "native", 
        strategy = "native"
    )
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    public Post() {}

    public Post(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

If you donot use GenericGenerator then, hibernate would execute the following queries when you do multiple save request:

```
SELECT next_val as id_val 
FROM hibernate_sequence FOR UPDATE

UPDATE hibernate_sequence 
SET next_val= 2 where next_val=1

SELECT next_val as id_val 
FROM hibernate_sequence FOR UPDATE

UPDATE hibernate_sequence 
SET next_val= 3 where next_val=1

SELECT next_val as id_val 
FROM hibernate_sequence FOR UPDATE

UPDATE hibernate_sequence 
SET next_val= 4 where next_val=3

INSERT INTO post (title, id) 
VALUES ('High-Performance Java Persistence', 1)

INSERT INTO post (title, id) 
VALUES ('High-Performance Java Persistence', 2)

INSERT INTO post (title, id) 
VALUES ('High-Performance Java Persistence', 3)
```

So using

```
@GenericGenerator(
    name = "native", 
    strategy = "native"
)
```

will generate the following queries:

```
INSERT INTO post (title) 
VALUES ('High-Performance Java Persistence')

INSERT INTO post (title) 
VALUES ('High-Performance Java Persistence')

INSERT INTO post (title) 
VALUES ('High-Performance Java Persistence')
```

Thus less queries executed to do the same operation, resulting in High Performance...